# Ant <taskdef> problem - classname not found

Tags: java, ant

Asumming I have a build.xml which is already given. I was ordered to add my own task to check some condition and let the build fail if it is not set.

In this build.xml there are already some tasks defined. So i thought i can simply write my own task, place it in a same package like the others and it will work.

```
<property name"build-dir" value="../base-build" />

<path id="classpath.build">
    <fileset dir="${build-dir}/lib" includes="*.jar" />
</path>

<taskdef name="givenTask" classname="test.build.somePackage.GivenTask" classpathref="classpath.build" />

<taskdef name="myAddedTask" classname="test.build.someOtherPackage.MyAddedTask" classpathref="classpath.build" />
```

The build.xml is in the directory base-build, and the packages in build-tools.
So my question is: If I copy the taskdef like above and it doesn't work, whats the reason for this? Do I need to add a reference to the path or something?

Comment: Are the equals signs after `classname` (e.g., should be `classname="test.build...."`) really missing or is that just a typo in your posting?

Comment: Sorry, these mistakes where just typos. I fixed them.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", is there an error that Ant is reporting? If not, you can try running "ant -v" to see what path Ant is referencing.

Answer (score 2):

`classname"test.package.build.someOtherPackage.MyAddedTask"` - we have two errors here, maybe typos: first, we miss a `=` after `classname`, second, the package name is not vaild because it contains a java keyword (`package`).

If the snippet was copy and pasted from the original code, then you have to fix it.